# Do all floors with the same game offer the same payout?

Tags: tiny-tower-vegas

Let's say I have two (or more) floors with the same game (poker, slots, etc). Will each of them offer the same payout for playing as the others of the same game? Or is there a difference in payout?

If there is no difference in payout, is look/name of the floor the only thing that makes it different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no different in payout per chip.

So, for example, betting 1 chip, each 21 floor has payouts of:

Push: 15 bux
Win: 30 bux
21: 80 bux

This payout is multiplied by the number of chips, if you bet more than one. (Ex: Betting 5 chips and getting a 21 would get you 400 bux.)

So yes, the only difference between each type of gambling floor is the aesthetic, and sometimes you get a character at a particular gambling floor.